# How do I resolve this passed by reference error?

Tags: php, drupal, warnings

This is part of a drupal module and I am getting this error:

```
Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in customheaderimage_get_last_argument()
```

My code is

```
function customheaderimage_get_last_argument() {
  return customheaderimage_dashtoslash(array_pop(explode('/', $_GET['q'])));
}
```

q contains a value like "admin/configure/customheaderimage/edit/node--2" the dashtoslash changes the -- to a slash with str_replace. so all of those chained functions return something like 'node/2' and it currently does and works. Just throws this warning

How do I resolve this warning message it does this in a few places?

Comment: why not pass by reference like `&$var` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop) takes an argument by reference:

> mixed array_pop ( array &$array )

It needs the reference because it modifies the array passed in as the argument. You're passing the result of a function and not a variable, so the reference doesn't make sense. In other words, you need to pass a variable as the argument.

```
function customheaderimage_get_last_argument() {
  $arr = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
  return customheaderimage_dashtoslash(array_pop($arr));
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. I had just solved it when you posted. Thanks! This code takes care of the issue.